# What is the cause of this error - Couldn't resolve host in PHP5 cURL

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm new to cURL. I'm trying to send a XML request and get its response as XML to a rest web application in a remote server. 
Below is the code I'm trying to send :

```
<?php
//header("refresh:5;url=form.html");
if(isset($_POST['create_xml'])){


$contact = "contact";
$first_name = $_POST["element_1"];
$last_name = $_POST["element_2"];
$email = $_POST["element_3"];
$country_code=$_POST["element_4_1"];
$contact_number=$_POST["element_4_2"].$_POST["element_4_3"];
$comments = $_POST["element_5"];

//if ($first_name && $last_name && $email && $contact_number && $comments) { 
//echo "Thank you for submitting your form. You may submit email service requests to our Support Center at:";
//} else { 
//exit("You have not filled out all the required fields. Place hit your back button and fill out all the required fields.");
//}

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$xml .= "<command>";
$xml .= "ADD_NEW_CONTACT";
$xml .= "</command>";
$xml .= "<data>";
$xml .= "<name>";
$xml .= $first_name.''.$last_name;
$xml .= "</name>";
$xml .= "<username>";
$xml .= $email;
$xml .= "</username>";
$xml .= "<preferredemail>";
$xml .= $email;
$xml .= "</preferredemail>";
$xml .= "<mobile>";
$xml .= "<countrycode>";
$xml .= $country_code;
$xml .= "</countrycode>";
$xml .= "<mobilenumber>";
$xml .= $contact_number;
$xml .= "</mobilenumber>";
$xml .= "</mobile>";
$xml .= "<gender>";
$xml .= "TBD";
$xml .= "</gender>";
$xml .= "</data>";
$xml .= "</groupzsyncreq>";

$xml =htmlentities($xml);
//echo $xml;


/**
     * Define POST URL and also payload
     */
    define('XML_POST_URL', 'http://www.testapp.com/test?request=');

    /**
     * Initialize handle and set options
     */
    $ch = curl_init();
    set_time_limit(0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, XML_POST_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close'));

    /**
     * Execute the request and also time the transaction
     */
    $start = array_sum(explode(' ', microtime()));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $stop = array_sum(explode(' ', microtime()));
    $totalTime = $stop - $start;

    /**
     * Check for errors
     */
    if ( curl_errno($ch) ) {
        $result = 'ERROR -> ' . curl_errno($ch) . ': ' . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        $returnCode = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        switch($returnCode){
            case 404:
                $result = 'ERROR -> 404 Not Found';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Close the handle
     */
    curl_close($ch);

    /**
     * Output the results and time
     */
    echo 'Total time for request: ' . $totalTime . "\n";
    echo $result;  

    /**
     * Exit the script
     */
    exit(0);
}
?>
```

Now, when I try to send the XML request from my local system , I get this error

```
Total time for request: 20.308043956757 ERROR -> 6: Couldn't resolve host 'www.testapp.com'.  But, `www.testapp.com` is fine and is up. How to solve this error.
```

Comment: The `http://www.testapp.com/` is not opening on my web-browser.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I'm not supposed to reveal the real domain name or application name. So I gave it as `http://www.testapp.com/`. But the name I'm working is up

Comment: Does that run on HTTPS or just HTTP ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Can u suggest me something for this

Comment: Can you simply try `file_get_contents($yoururl);` and tell me what's the result ?

Comment: `Cannot parse XML request` This is what I got

Comment: So is that an XML file you are trying to retrieve???

Answer (score 0):

```
define('XML_POST_URL', 'http://www.testapp.com/test?request=');
```

I think , this is not complete.
Can you check your end point url under service tag at end of wsdl.

Comment: The URL is completed with the XML tags given to the URL after request

Comment: ohh, my bad. Can you replace this host with the IP address of host, if its possible. You should check your server's DNS settings

Answer (score 0):

Change this http header as you are using xml

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
```

Also use this curl option for http POST

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```